# How to get the hotkey definition if a shortcut is pressed?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys, keycode

For example, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in this order, how I do get the corresponding hotkey definition?

I expect something like the following:

```
; pseudo code
*::MsgBox %A_ThisHotkey% was pressed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get what you mean, this
`^+!c::MsgBox, % A_ThisHotkey`
works just fine?

---

Or do you mean something like this?

```
Gui, Add, Hotkey, vHotkeyName
Gui, Add, Button, gPrintHotkey, % "Print Hotkey"
Gui, Show
return

PrintHotkey()
{
    global HotkeyName
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    MsgBox, % HotkeyName
}

GuiClose()
{
    ExitApp
}
```

See the [hotkey gui control](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Hotkey).